# Alternating settings at django runtime

Tags: python, django

I need to keep some settings in RAM. I created file "cache_values.py"

```
class CacheValue:
    pass
```

I want to use it as variable container for my needs.

I'm writing some settings to "CacheValue" on server start:

```
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
from modifier.cache_values import CacheValue

def cache_start_values():
   CacheValue.page_publish_dates={}

   pages=Page.objects.all()
   for page in pages:
       CacheValue.page_publish_dates[page.pk]=page.last_publish_date

   CacheValue.last_publish_date=max(CacheValue.page_publish_dates.values())
```

Also, when I'm saving some model - I change these settings

```
CacheValue.page_publish_dates[self.pk]=self.last_publish_date
CacheValue.last_publish_date=max(CacheValue.page_publish_dates.values())
```

But when I want to use this settings in my templates, by adding them with context processor as variables - some magic begins.

```
from modifier.cache_values import CacheValue
def add_for_cache_info(request):
    context_extras = {}
    context_extras['page_publish_dates']=CacheValue.page_publish_dates
    context_extras['last_publish_date_all_pages']=CacheValue.last_publish_date
    if "current_page" in request.__dict__:
        context_extras['last_publish_date']=CacheValue.page_publish_dates[request.current_page.pk]   

    return context_extras
```

In template

```
  {{ page_publish_dates }}
  {{ last_publish_date_all_pages }}
```

Values that I see in rendered template alternates between old(before model save) and new(after model save) every time I refersh a page. 0_0 0_0

If I save model(change value) second time - it will alterante between the oldest value and the new one.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple Django processes are running, and **each process** has its own copy of `CacheValue`, one with the value in question, but most without. Use [Django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) instead.

Comment: Correct answer - multiple processes with multiple threads cause similar issues. Caching framework is good choice here, but do not use [Local memory caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) backend, as it is not shared between processes. There are also some solutions for distributed coordination (such as Zookeeper), but they are rather an overkill. Memcached or some key-value store look also like one, but it is hard to find other reliable alternative.

Comment: So, as I understand, there is no way to keep sоme changing at runtime settings in ram, only using python variables and classes.  Am I right?

Comment: I am asking, because I don't want to use memcache to store only date, and wait when I get it from there